# Selecting multiple range from two different workbook to make a one complete graph

Tags: excel, vba, graph

```
Sub Macro1()    
 Macro1 Macro    
    Dim k_Month As Range
    Dim PrevYear As Range
    Dim CurrYear As Range
    Dim RelFC As Range
    Dim PropFC As Range

Set PropFC = Workbooks("ETKR_Sales_Tracking_MBR.xlsx").Worksheets("Year To Date").Range("C849:N849")
Set RelFC = Workbooks("ETKR_Sales_Tracking_MBR.xlsx").Worksheets("Year To Date").Range("C1061:N1061")

Set k_Month = Workbooks("Gap_Analysis.xlsx").Worksheets("SA2 KR").Range("U4:AF4")
Set PrevYear = Workbooks("Gap_Analysis.xlsx").Worksheets("SA2 KR").Range("AO6:AZ6")
Set CurrYear = Workbooks("Gap_Analysis.xlsx").Worksheets("SA2 KR").Range("U6:AF6")

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "Proposed Forecast"
    .Values = PropFC
    .XValues = k_Month
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "Released Forecast"
    .Values = RelFC
    .XValues = k_Month
End With

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "Current Year"
    .Values = CurrYear
    .XValues = k_Month
End With
    
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "Previous Year"
    .Values = PrevYear
    .XValues = k_Month
End With    

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Workbooks("Gap_Analysis.xlsx").Sheets( _
        "SA2 KR").Range("AO6:AZ6,U6:AF6,U4:AF4")

End Sub
```

As you can see the title, I am trying to use multiple range from two different excel file to make one complete graph. There are 4 ranges which are, proposed forecast, released forecast, current year, and previous year.

When I combined those all together and run, the graph does not show current year and previous year data since they are in different excel file but only shows proposed forecast, and released forecast.

And I do now that I can solve this problem by bringing the data from year.file to forecast.file. But I do not want to do that because it will take too much time for me. Please give me a guide to solve this challenging VBA range problem

## just another comment: Do not use Excel when you are dealing with big data. It is wise to use R or python and its easier than slow, stupid excel.

Comment: By the way, the image file is complete and indented clearly.

Answer (score 0):

What if, instead of referencing the external ranges directly, you tweak your code to create links to them in a central worksheet in your main file?  This way, the graph references only ranges in the main file, and all your source numbers are in front of you--as well as the user--to reference when looking at the graph.

To emphasize:  You would not be bringing in data--just linking it using VBA code.